# Python reading file and get a substring

Tags: python, string, raspberry-pi

I read a file which contains:

```
> hello world
```

Using the following code to read this file, but I can't read a part of it

```
with open("/home/pi/example1.txt") as f1:
    test = f1.readlines(0)
    print (test)
    print (test[0:2])
```

expected output:

```
Hello world
He
```

Output what I get

```
['helloworld\r\n']
['helloworld\r\n']
```

What is the right (and SIMPLE) way to get a part of a substring what I grab from a file?

Comment: use 'f1.readline()

Answer (score 2):

`readlines()` returns a list, as you can see in your output the string is actually part of a one-item list:

```
>>> f = ['helloworld\r\n']
>>> f[0][0:2]
'he'
```

To fix your original code, you need to move the 0 *after* the readlines call:

```
test = f1.readlines()[0]
```

However, as you are using the `with` statement, your life is a lot simpler:

```
with open("/home/pi/example1.txt") as f1:
    for line in f1:
        print(line)
        print(line[0:2])
```

Comment: Thank you, for the clear and simple explanation. It works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Just change a bit to :

```
with open("/home/pi/example1.txt") as f1:
    for test in f1:
        print(test)
        print(test[0:2])
```

Other way readline returns a list then just use the indexing line readline()[0]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct code that you want.

```
with open("/home/pi/example1.txt") as f1:
    test = f1.readlines(0)
    print (test[0])
    print (test[0][0:2])
```

But alternatively you can use the following approach.

```
with open("/home/pi/example1.txt") as f1:
    test = f1.readline()
    print (test)
    print (test[0:2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **.strip()** function which is available to remove all the white space and new line characters from a string

```
    with open('../../xx.txt','r') as fi:
        for line in fi:
           print(line.strip())
           print(line[0:2])
```

I didn't used the **.strip()** method in the second print statement because we are just getting the initial part of a string . so it will not be a new line character(let's hope so). In case if you want you can use for that line also

```
    print(line[0:2].strip())
```

strip() method will be really helpful specially if you are using the string later for any comparison.

Answer (score 1):

the readlines return a list

use test[0] for substring